# Is mingw-w64 not compatible with semaphore?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

I wrote a multi-thread program and tested OK in `Linux:g++12.2.0,clang++15.0.2-1` and `Windows:Visual Studio 2022 17.4.2`, but caused a deadlock in `Windows:MingW-w64`.

After a lot of debugging, I found a simple kind of code would cause a deadlock at sometimes when compiled by MingW-w64, no matter with or without optimize options, usually less than 10000 loops would enough to block the progress.

I'm not sure if there is something unsafe in this code or just MingW-w64 has a bug with semaphore.

While in Linux or compiling by Visual Studio would run forever.

And, if replace `acquire()` to `try_acquire_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000))`, the program would also run forever under MingW-w64 (without pause).

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <semaphore>
using namespace std;

std::counting_semaphore<3> cs1(0), cs2(0);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    thread th(
        []()
        {
            for (int j = 0;; j--)
            {
                cs1.release();
                printf("%d\n", j);
                cs2.acquire();
            }
        });

    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        cs2.release();
        printf("%d\n", i);
        cs1.acquire();
    }

    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

this is last rows of output in one run:

```
...
-804
805
806
-805
-806
-807
-808
807
808
809
810
-809
-810
-811
811
812
(blocked)
```

Seems like the `release` operation before `print(i=812)` had not wake the thread waiting at `acquire` after `print(j=-811)`.

Both `MingW-w64-g++` and `MingW-w64-clang++` have this problem, this is the info of MingW-w64 (the thread and exception model should be `POSIX-seh`):

```
winlibs personal build version gcc-12.2.0-llvm-14.0.6-mingw-w64ucrt-10.0.0-r2

This is the winlibs 64-bit standalone build of:
- GCC 12.2.0
- GDB 12.1
- LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 14.0.6
- MinGW-w64 10.0.0 (linked with ucrt)
- GNU Binutils 2.39
- GNU Make 4.3
- PExports 0.47
- dos2unix 7.4.3
- Yasm 1.3.0
- NASM 2.15.05
- JWasm 2.12pre
- ninja 1.11.0
- doxygen 1.9.5

This build was compiled with GCC 12.2.0 and packaged on 2022-08-28.

Please check out http://winlibs.com/ for the latest personal build.
```